# Specifying entry point for storyboard (not the initial view)

Tags: objective-c, ios, storyboard

My project has many tabs. Each tab is implemented using xib files. For one particular view controller I want to use storyboard. I am relatively new to the storyboards and wanted to know how to specify the entry point for the storyboard.

My current code looks like this.

```
- (UIViewController *)viewControllerForTabDocs {
    DocsViewController *vc = [[DocsViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    return nav;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try the followings

```
UIStoryboard *storybrd = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
DocsViewController *controller =[storybrd instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"docsViewController"];
UINavigationController* nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:controller];
```